# Constructing FormParam request in WSO2

Tags: xml, wso2

Constructing `FormParam` request in WSO2 to make a request to a REST Service which will accept `FormParam` with some specified key. Client will just make a request with XML in form of string to `esb` to invoke that service which is configured in wso2 `esb`. We need to take that XML and construct form inside esb and add that XML as value with some specified key which will be accepted by REST `EndPoint`.